# LINQ include multiple children

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a construction that store databases metadata

```
public class Database {
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Table> Tables { get; set; }
}

public class Table {
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ForeingKey> ForeingKeys { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to retrieve all database related data in one only query with LINQ
I can query tables and one child entity from databases

```
            var qry = from d in context.Databases
                         .Include(x => x.Tables.Select( c => c.Fields))
                      select d;
```

But, how can I read two childs from Tables collection? Something like this

```
 var qry = from d in context.Databases
             .Include(x => x.Tables.Include(t => t.Fields).Include(t => t.ForeingKeys))
           select d;
```

Comment: This is pretty terrible for performance though.. You might want to look into explicit loading which would let you query the underlying collection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468074%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var qry = from d in context.Databases
    .Include("Tables.Fields")
    .Include("Tables.ForeingKeys")
  select d;
```

EF will automatically include tables for you and then include those navigation properties in the query.

Comment: your query throws error 'Name or type duplicates in an assembly.'
I think it's due we include the `Tables` object twice.

Comment: Try context.Set<Database>().Include(...).  [IDbSet.Include(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220202(v=vs.113).aspx) has more details in the "Remarks" section.

Comment: Tables.* needs to be duplicated in the subsequent Include() because EF would not know what property to grab the next varieble from otherwise. Chaining the Include() is on the Databases set and scoped appropriately.

Comment: Tacoman667, your response is correct. The error is due a bug in EF
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2228

Answer (score 14):

Another way to achieve the same is

```
        var qry = from d in context.Databases
                      .Include(x => x.Tables)
                      .Include(x => x.Tables.Select(c => c.Fields))
                      .Include(x => x.Tables.Select(f => f.ForeingKeys))
                  select d;
```

I prefer do not use literals.

Comment: Plus one for not using string literals. It makes refactoring a nightmare.

Comment: Just in case, you need this for it to work `using System.Data.Entity;`